# Array based MinHeap

Tags: python, algorithm, heap, min-heap

I am trying to implement a function that turns a list into a MinHeap. I cannot see where I am going wrong.

```
def min_heapify(nums):
    n = len(nums) - 1
    i = n // 2  # last parent

    while i >= 1:
        k = i
        v = nums[k]
        min_heap = False
        while not min_heap and 2 * k <= n:
            j = 2 * k
            if j + 1 <= n:
                if nums[j + 1] < nums[j]:
                    j += 1
            if nums[k] < nums[j]:
                min_heap = True
            else:
                nums[k] = nums[j]
                k = j
        nums[k] = v
        i -= 1
```

Example Input:

```
a_list = [0, 5, 2, 3, 4]
min_heapify(a_list)
```

Output  (the 4 is incorrect):

```
print("Min Heapify", a_list)  # Min Heapify [0, 2, 5, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Both the 3 and the 4 are incorrect, no? Looks like the 3 and the 5 need swapping?

Comment: That is a correctly sorted min-heap. The children of 0 are 2 and 5, which are greater than 0. The children of 2 are 3 and 4, which again are greater than the parent. The min-node is at the root, 0. The children of a node at position n in the array are at 2n+1 and 2n+2.

Comment: @TWReever 0 is used as a placeholder for the 0th index, since for an array implementation you need this as 2n is 0.

Comment: @Wizard there are actually two ways to represent a heap as an array. A 0-based approach where the children of n are located at 2n+1 and 2n+2 and a 1-based approach, as you stated with children at 2n and 2n+1.

Comment: The simplest way fix to your code is to change the line `if nums[k] < nums[j]` to `if v < nums[j]`. If you do that, there's no need to swap `nums[j]` and `nums[k]` as suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be swaping `num[j]` and `num[k]`, where you are just assigning `nums[k] = nums[j]`:

```
def min_heapify(nums):
    n = len(nums) - 1
    i = n // 2  # last parent

    while i >= 1:
        k = i
        v = nums[k]
        min_heap = False
        while not min_heap and 2 * k <= n:
            j = 2 * k
            if j + 1 <= n:
                if nums[j + 1] < nums[j]:
                    j += 1
            if nums[k] < nums[j]:
                min_heap = True
            else:
                # HERE: Need to swap num[j] and num[k]
                [nums[j], nums[k]] = [nums[k], nums[j]]
                k = j
        nums[k] = v
        i -= 1

a_list = [0, 11, 5, 2, 3, 4, 7, 17, 6, 1]
min_heapify(a_list)
print(a_list)

# prints: [0, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 17, 6, 11]
```